# Can't use libspotify 12 in android app

Tags: android, android-ndk, spotify

I'm trying to load libspotify in my android app using NDK.
I'm using the library libspotify++ and jlibspotify. everything seems to be loaded but it crashes when libspotify is trying to load the library "libspotify.so.12"

I cannot use symbolic links in android.

Code:

```
public class Session {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("spotify");
        System.loadLibrary("jlibspotify");
    }

}
```

Log:

```
05-29 17:27:22.559: D/dalvikvm(32606): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
05-29 17:27:25.527: D/dalvikvm(32606): Trying to load lib /data/data/se.warting.spotify/lib/libspotify.so 0x41692100
05-29 17:27:25.535: D/dalvikvm(32606): Added shared lib /data/data/se.warting.spotify/lib/libspotify.so 0x41692100
05-29 17:27:25.535: D/dalvikvm(32606): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/se.warting.spotify/lib/libspotify.so 0x41692100, skipping init
05-29 17:27:25.543: D/dalvikvm(32606): Trying to load lib /data/data/se.warting.spotify/lib/libjlibspotify.so 0x41692100
05-29 17:27:27.637: W/dalvikvm(32606): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lse/sony/tunefeud/spotiwrap/Session;
05-29 17:27:28.824: D/AndroidRuntime(32606): Shutting down VM
05-29 17:27:28.824: W/dalvikvm(32606): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a421f8)


05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    at se.warting.spotify.PocActivity.onCreate(PocActivity.java:18)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1936]:   118 could not load needed library 'libspotify.so.12' for 'libjlibspotify.so' (load_library[1091]: Library 'libspotify.so.12' not found)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    at se.warting.spotify.spotiwrap.Session.<clinit>(Session.java:6)
05-29 17:27:28.855: E/AndroidRuntime(32606):    ... 15 more
```

This is what i get from objdump:

```
$arm-linux-androideabi-objdump -p libs/armeabi/libjlibspotify.so  | grep NEEDED
  NEEDED               libspotify.so.12
  NEEDED               libstdc++.so
  NEEDED               libm.so
  NEEDED               libc.so
  NEEDED               libdl.so
$arm-linux-androideabi-objdump -p libs/armeabi/libspotify.so  | grep NEEDED
  NEEDED               libm.so
  NEEDED               libc.so
  NEEDED               libdl.so
```

Does anyone know what do do to get it work?

Comment: Can you check what shared libraries does libjlibspotify.so file depend upon? You can do this with objdump using this command: `arm-linux-androideabi-objdump.exe -p libtest.so | grep NEEDED`

Comment: I could not format the output so i edited my question, i guess the needed library is the problem, how do i change it?

Comment: Your log shows that libspotify.so is being loaded fine — it looks like jlibspotify is incorrectly depending on libspotify.so.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from Mārtiņš is correct, it should be build with Android's NDK build system.
When don't having controle over the library there is a workaround:

Instead of loading the library with System.loadLibrary( "JLibSpotify" );
i manualy copied /data/data/se.warting.spotify/lib/libspotify.so to  /data/data/se.warting.spotify/libspotify.so.12
And then loaded the library with:

```
System.load("/data/data/se.warting.spotify/libspotify.so.12");
```

After that i could load jlibspotify as normal:

```
System.loadLibrary("jlibspotify");
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll just break out my Java/JVM skills here and try applying them on Android/Dalvik.

1. `System.loadLibrary()` expects a JNI library name as its argument. In this case libspotify is not (and never is) a JNI library, but libjlibspotify seems to be. Note how the first call whines in the log about the missing `JNI_OnLoad` function. This is usually a good hint. `System.loadLibrary()` does however accept any shared library as long as it can find it, and that's why the call doesn't fail in this scenario.
2. Dependent libraries of a JNI library are loaded automatically by the platform's built-in shared library loading mechanisms. In this case, libjlibspotify depends on `libspotify.so.12`, so if there is such a file available in the loader's path, then this should be loaded automatically by the system whenever libjlibspotify is loaded.

   Hence, the proper Java code in this case should be:

   ```
   public class Session {
       static {
           System.loadLibrary("jlibspotify");
       }
   }
   ```

   However, if the dependent library is not found as part of the `System.loadLibrary()` invocation, then that call will fail with an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` (see the log about the missing dependent `libspotify.so.12` file).
3. libspotify 12 currently ships in the archive as `libspotify.so.12.1.45` (with some symlinks `libspotify.so` and `libspotify.so.12` pointing to that file). I don't know anything about how libjlibspotify has been built in this scenario, but if it is the case that the symlinks aren't relevant in the Android setting, then libjlibspotify should instead be built to load `libspotify.so.12.1.45` from the archive, no renaming needed.

Comment: 1. is not true. You can load with System.loadLibrary() any shared library (so maybe later you can search symbols in your own process). Even if those dependant libraries doesn't contain any JNI code. Having no JNI_OnLoad is also completely valid situation even for JNI library.

Comment: jlibspotify is built with Androids ndk-build. libspotify is not.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to change build process of how you are creating the libspotify to have proper name.

Easiest way would be to use Android NDK build system - it will correctly compile and link the libraries.

Comment: It certainly will, but i can't do it. i Guess the problem is coused by spotify.